# This keyword Java name similiar to parameter variable name

Tags: java

My understanding of the `this` keyword in java is that you are referencing instance variables as opposed to local variables within a method to save confusion between both names.

As stupid as the question may seem, why would I have a parameter variable names similar to instance variable names? Or exactly the same name... what is the purpose of having similar names?

I'm really just starting out in java so forgive my ignorance

Thanks

Comment: Constructor or method parameters, for example.  Why call it `a` in the argument list and `b` as the property?  Sometime, it's just simple to use `a` and `a`

Comment: Might be simpler to realize the variable name in both cases represents something, like "age" or "name". Why spend effort coming up with different words for "age" when you can just use `this.`

Comment: You are basically asking a "why do people chose to do X rather than Y" question.  There are lots of answers.  One is "because they can".  Another is "because they prefer X to Y" for reasons that don't seem significant to you.  Another is "because they didn't think of Y".  And so on. Either way, it comes down to people making choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common use of this feature is when creating a constructor or accessor methods (getter/setter).

```java
public class MyClass {
  private String name;

  public MyClass(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Note that parameter names are usually part of the publicly-visible API — they are shown in generated Javadocs and by IDE code tools.  Therefore, often the "correct" parameter name to show to users of your class are an exact match for the internal fields inside the class.

Additionally, this means not having to come up with unique names for the parameters (or fields) just to avoid having conflicting names for a parameter with a very limited scope.